# Вывести картинку в RecyclerView

Tags: android

Использую библиотеку Glide для вывода картинок в элементы RecyclerView. Вот такой адаптер есть

Адаптер

```
public class BludoAdapter extends RecyclerViewCursorAdapter<BludoAdapter.BludoViewHolder> {

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
    int lenght;

    public interface OnItemClickListener {
        void onItemClick(long id);
        void onFavoriteButtonClick(long id, boolean isFavorite);
    }

    public void setOnItemClickListener(final OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener) {
        this.mItemClickListener = mItemClickListener;
    }

    //Конструктор класса адаптера
    public BludoAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context);

        setupCursorAdapter(null, 0, R.layout.item, false);
    }

    //Возвращает ViewHolder для работы с адаптером
    @Override
    public BludoViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new BludoViewHolder(mCursorAdapter.newView(mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor(), parent));
    }

    /**
     * Moves the Cursor of the CursorAdapter to the appropriate position and binds the view for
     * that item.
     */
    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(BludoViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Move cursor to this position
        mCursorAdapter.getCursor().moveToPosition(position);

        // Set the ViewHolder
        setViewHolder(holder);

        // Bind this view
        mCursorAdapter.bindView(null, mContext, mCursorAdapter.getCursor());

    }

    //ViewHolder для отображения данных на экране
    public class BludoViewHolder extends RecyclerViewCursorViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
        public final TextView txtBludo;
        public final TextView txtRecept;
        public final ImageButton btnfavorite;
        public final ImageView img;
        String favorites;
        int id;

        public BludoViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);

            txtBludo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBludo);
            txtRecept = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecept);
            btnfavorite = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.btnfavorite);
            img = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.img);

            view.setOnClickListener(this);
            btnfavorite.setOnClickListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void bindCursor(Cursor cursor) {
            // переменные id, like переносим в поле класса-холдера, чтобы был доступ из всех методов
            id = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Bluda._ID));
            favorites = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Bluda.COL_LIKE));
            String bludo  = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Bluda.COL_BLUDO));
            String recept = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Bluda.COL_RECEPT));
            String strImg = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DBContract.Bluda.COL_IMAGE));
            txtBludo.setText(bludo );
            Glide.with(context).load(Uri.parse("file:///android_asset/img/" + strImg + ".jpg")).into(img);
            txtRecept.setText(recept);
            // конструкцию с if-else упрощаем

            if (favorites.equals("1")) {
                btnfavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_yellow);
            } else {
                btnfavorite.setImageResource(R.drawable.icon_star_outline_black);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            //int position = getAdapterPosition();
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.btnfavorite:
                    mItemClickListener.onFavoriteButtonClick(id, favorites.equals("1"));
                    break;
                default:
                    mItemClickListener.onItemClick(id);
            }
        }

    }

    public void setFilterLength(int lenght) {
        this.lenght = lenght;
    }

    public int getLenght() {
        return lenght;
    }
}
```

Так вот при приложение вылетает при запуске, а именно на контекст в Glide ругается и выдает вот такое

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You cannot start a load on a null
>   Context

Как правильнее сделать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужен реальный контекст, а не просто переменная с таким именем. Получить его можно, например, из конструктора, раз вы его туда передаете:

```
public class BludoAdapter extends RecyclerViewCursorAdapter<BludoAdapter.BludoViewHolder> {

    OnItemClickListener mItemClickListener;
    int lenght;
    final Context context; // выносим контекст в поле класса

    ...

    //Конструктор класса адаптера
    public BludoAdapter(Context context) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context; // присваиваем контекст активити в поле класса
        ...
    }
}
```

теперь можно обращаться к контексту в любом месте класса по его имени `context`

Comment: Спасибо. получилось